Exception in Transfer Hook program
I have a token mint with a Transfer fee and Transfer hook, I also have a hook program that limits the no of tokens sent in a single transaction. How do I make an exception in the hook program to bypass this transfer limit for the Tax/Treasury wallet which collects the fees? Tax/Treasury wallet is defined as Transfer Fee Authority for the mint token.

To exempt the Tax/Treasury wallet from the transfer limit in your hook program:
Retrieve the Transfer Fee Authority wallet address associated with the mint token.
During transfer validation, check if the destination wallet matches the Transfer Fee Authority address.
If the destination wallet matches, bypass the transfer limit check.
Otherwise, enforce the transfer limit as usual.
Try this hope it help you !
